# Angular4 - Apply class based on value of param

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to dynamically create `bootstrap badges` based on the value being passed to the div.

**HTML**

```
<div
  *ngFor="let tag of event.tags">
  <span [ngClass]="setTagClass('tag')">
    {{tag}}
  </span>
</div>
```

**Component Function**

```
  public setTagClass(tag){
    switch (tag) {
      case 'Gaming': {
        'badge badge-pill badge-default';
        break;
      }
      case 'Home': {
        'badge badge-pill badge-success';
        break;
      }
      case 'Social': {
        'badge badge-pill badge-primary';
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

However it's giving me a `_co.setClass is not a function` error spam.

Before this what I attempted to do was daisy chain dynamic versions. IE:

```
<div
  *ngFor="let tag of event.tags">
  <span [ngClass]="{'badge badge-pill badge-default': tag == 'Gaming',
                    'badge badge-pill badge-primary': tag == 'Social'
    }">
    {{tag}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Ugly - But decent concept... except not -

For some reason the LAST badge to be rendered meeting a requirement looked correct - But the ones before it lose the `badge badge-pill` section of their class, but maintained the `badge-{color}` section, so it ended up looking like a highlight.

I've seen a lot of different information on `ngClass`, `class.class` etc and unsure which one is the proper choice to make this work. I feel like this should belong in the controller but I can't seem to make it feedback to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed the `tag` as a string to the function - `'tag'`. Remove the `''` from the expression and then return the result from the function.

```
<div
  *ngFor="let tag of event.tags">
  <span [ngClass]="setTagClass(tag)">
    {{tag}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Function

```
public setTagClass(tag) {
    switch (tag) {
      case 'Gaming': 
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-default';
      case 'Home': 
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-success';
      case 'Social': 
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-primary';
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, but same error as prior.

`ERROR TypeError: _co.setTagClass is not a function
    at Object.View_EventDetailComponent_1.currVal_1 `

Comment: Have you returned the string?

Comment: Yes - I modified both portions.

Comment: Never mind you made me realize my issue. My function was placed within my `event-form` component, not my `event-detail` (The view). Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @DNorthrup Glad :)